# Leaving a Space for a Variable in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables

I'm sure I've seen this done before but without knowing what it's called I'm struggling to find any tutorials etc.

Basically i want to store a string in MySQL but leave a space for a different variable each time.

I'm pretty sure I've seen a better way, but just to explain the problem I'm trying to get around... I want something like the following string stored in my MySQL table, that I'd then put into a PHP variable:

```
"This user has ##variable## points left before reaching the next
level"
```

Then in PHP I'd do:

```
str_replace("##variable##", $new_var, $mysql_string);
```

I know the above way would work, but I'm sure there's a better way that I've seen somewhere. Have i imagined it?

Comment: Are you looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php ?

Comment: Why store all the extra, static, data in your database? Just store the variable, and use PHP to display the rest. `echo "\"This user has $sqlResult points left before reaching the next level.\"";` This way you aren't wasting space saving the same data over and over.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 hi, because the string will change too depending the situation, but there are a lot of different string changes for each situation.

Comment: @John Ok, that makes sense then. With the example/information provided it seemed like it wasn't the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sprintf(gettext("some text %s"),$variable);
```

Where `%s` is replaced by `$variable`.